# Production Grade Server Software

Tags: apache, deployment, web, xampp

I am currently using XAMPP to test and Run my website on my Laptop.

Is there any (Good,Production Grade,Free,AMP based) server software?

Or Can I manually fix the security holes in XAMPP (like no password for 'root') to bring it up to production level?

Platform : Windows
Technologies: Apache, MySQL, PHP
Requirements: Hosting on Own server
Priveleges: Easy installation and configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best off just setting things up yourself. It's not that difficult, especially since there are scores and scores of guides around the web. Trying to bring XAMPP up to production quality would be just as much work. Here are some links:

- [Ubuntu LAMP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)
- [Debian LAMP](http://wiki.debian.org/LaMp)
- [Fedora LAMP](http://fedorasolved.org/server-solutions/lamp-stack)
- [Arch Linux LAMP](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP)
- [WAMP (Windows)](http://wizardswhinings.blogspot.com/2007/02/complete-idiots-guide-to-wamp.html)

You can easily find more by doing a Google search.

Comment: I think i had corrected the question to include that windows was the platform.

is WAMP production grade?

Comment: WAMP isn't any particular piece of software, it's just the LAMP stack with Windows substituted for Linux. The guide I linked to walks you through installing Apache, MySQL, and PHP on Windows and linking them together.

Comment: oh yes! ya got it! +1 fer zat.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use official Apache? It's the most-used Production http server in the world.

Can you expand your question with details on your platform and requirements?

Comment: I think he wants something packaged so he can easily install without little configuration (like XAMPP).

Comment: then he wants XAMPP. Oh, right...  Apache's not so hard to learn and is the A part in XAMPP anyway, so you just need to learn to configure it to manually remove any configuration problems.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off configuring the full stack yourself. This ensures that you know what's running, and how it's configured. Even if you use a bundle (I highly recommend [Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/) if you do), you would need to run through the service configurations anyway. Never rely on anything out-of-box in a production environment.

If you do configure the stack yourself, Google is your friend, and there are plenty of resources here to help as well.

Comment: zend is paid                    ?

Comment: There is both a commercial and a free community edition. The commercial edition offers automatic updates and a few extras, but nothing you would need unless you run a huge server farm.

Comment: Actually the free version also does automatic updates, as long as you install it via a package manager such as RPM or APT.